Building Time Parameters for Lognormal Model
I am trying to figure out how to build the parameters for time for my lognormal model (building a velocity profile)
the model has N lognormal curves, and each has a t and t0 parameter. While I understand how to build the other parameters not shown in this question, I am confused on how these parameters are created.

The table below displays the mean and standard deviation used to generate values for the parameters t and t0 using a Gaussian random distribution. In this context, the parameter t represents the total duration of the motion, which is divided into N segments to accommodate the N lognormal curves. Each Lognormal adds an additional time duration to the total time, denoted as ti , and has a starting time referred to as t0i . the duration ti for each curve is calculated using the Gaussian distribution, and the starting time t 0i marks the beginning of each lognormal curve's effect.

Table of Parameters for Time



Parameter
Mean
Standard Deviation
Lower Bound




t (duration)
0.75
0.3
0.4


ti (additional)
0.3
0.05
0.1


t0i
t0i-1 + t/N
t/3N
0.1



What I am trying to figure out, is if I were to say want to use 4 Lognormal Curves (N = 4) what would my output be. Would the initial t value remain the same throughout?
This is my current interpretation:



Stroke(N)
t
ti
t0i




1
0.75
0.3
0.1875


2
0.75
0.3
0.375


3
0.75
0.3
0.5625


4
0.75
0.3
0.75



But this doesn't make sense as I am not sure what the ti is providing.
Thank you in Advance

Welcome to Cross Validated! I'm not completely clear on what type of data you are trying to model with this approach. Could you please edit the question to provide more background on the subject matter, the nature of your data, and the hypotheses that you want to test? Please do that by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

@EdM I added an edit clarifying. It is for a velocity Profile and overlapping lognormals

Thanks, but I'm not sure that I understand what a "velocity profile" is, and I suspect that will also be the case for most others who frequent this site. Please provide details about what you have measured and are trying to model, what the "velocity profile" represents, and some background about why you need N lognormal curves to fit it. It looks like you have included a quote from some text or reference; providing a link to that would also help.
